# A theoretical result concerning image and pre image set

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am stuck in proofing a result concerning image and pre-image set. The theorem is stated as follow.

Let A, B be sets, and f:A→B be a function. Then

(a) $f(A)⊂ B $.

(b) $f^{-1} (B) = A $.

For (a), I start by picking any object y and suppose y belongs to f(A). Then I cannot proceed further. I know my target is to show that y belongs to B (by definition of subset). How shall I make use of the definition of image set?

For (b), shall I begin with similar things with (a)?

I also know that the definition of image and preimage set are as follow.

Let A, B be set and f:A→B be the function from A to B.

Let S be a subset of A. The image set of the set S under f is defined to be the set {y ∈ B:there exist some x ∈ S such that y=f(x)}.

Let U be a subset of B. The preimage set of the set U under f is defined to be the set {x ∈ A:there exist some y ∈ U such that y=f(x)}.

The definition of function:

Let D, R be sets and H be a subset of the Cartesian product of A and B. The relation (D,R,H) is said to be a function from domain D to range R with graph H if both (E), (U) hold:

(E): For any x ∈ D, there exist some y ∈ R such that (x, y) ∈ H.

(U): For any x ∈ D, for any y, z ∈ R, if (x, y) ∈ H and (x, z) ∈ H, then y =z.

Comment: You need to know precisely what a function $A\to B$ is, and the definitions of the image and preimage sets. Can you add these into your post?

Comment: I have added the definition that I use in my course in the post. Thanks! And may I know that is that accurate enough for me to complete the proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) is trivial since if $f(a)\in f(A)$, then $f(a)\in B$ because $f:A\rightarrow B$.

(b) $f^{-1}(B):=\{a\in A :f(a)\in B\}$. So you have directly $f^{-1}(B)\subset A$. For the other inclusion, if $a\in A$, then $f(a)\in B$ (cf (a)), so that $A\subset f^{-1}(B)$.